# I am trying to get dynamic values for my dropdown list

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am trying to get dynamic values for my dropdown list. But unable to call my action class through which i am returning list to my jsp.

This is my jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>

<label for="clientSelect">Select Client</label>
<sj:select href="clientListAction" id="clientName" name="clientName" list="clientList"  cssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
```

This is my action class through which I am trying to return the list to JSP

```
@ParentPackage("layout")
@Namespace("/m")
public class ClientListAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{

@Autowired 
@Qualifier("AccountService")
ObjectFactory<AccountService> AccountServiceFactory;

List<String> clientList;

public List<String> getClientList() {
 return clientList;
}

public void setClientList(List<String> clientList) {
 this.clientList = clientList;
}

@Action(value = "clientListAction", results = {      @Result(name="success",type="json" ) })
public String execute() throws Exception{
System.out.println("inside clientListAction of ClientListAction");
Userr user = ( (OptionsUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUserr();
user =  Userr.findUserr(user.getId());
clientList = getUsersClientList(user);
 return SUCCESS;
 }

private List<String> getUsersClientList(Userr userId){
  AccountService accountService = AccountServiceFactory.getObject();
  return accountService.getUsersClientList(userId);
}


@Override
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

}
```

Problem is my I am unable to call my action class ? How to achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean "I am unable to call my action class"? Did you call it? What happened?

Comment: @RomanC inside the select tag i Have written " href "  in a hope to call my action . but it seems to be not working ? How do i call action inside the select tag ?

Comment: You should write url that is mapped to the action.

Comment: Does it change if you write href="/clientListAction" ?